# Возвращаем значение из heap

Tags: winapi, ассемблер, masm32, x86

Как получить обратно из heap значение, которое туда записывается при помощи `RtlMoveMemory`. Вот весь код:

```
include E:\masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
HeapAlloc PROTO STDCALL :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD
myfree proto :DWORD

.data
hmyHeap dd 0
mtest db "test, testtttt dj a test ",0
hMylp1 dd 0

.code

main:

invoke GetProcessHeap
mov hmyHeap,eax
invoke HeapAlloc,hmyHeap,HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,300h
mov hMylp1,eax
invoke RtlMoveMemory,eax,addr mtest,10
invoke HeapFree,hmyHeap,NULL,hMylp1

end main
```

Comment: Но у вас же есть явный адрес области памяти, который вернул HeapAlloc берите и работайте с ней как с обычной памятью. RtlMoveMemory просто копирует кусок памяти, точно так же вы могли сделать сами обычным циклом с mov или rep movs

Comment: @Mike расскажите пожалуйста как это "обычным циклом с mov"?

Comment: mov esi, eax; mov edi, addr mtest; и далее в цикле mov eax,[esi]; mov [edi],eax и увеличиваем esi, edi на 4 (кол-во скопированных байт) ну или используем другую переменную счетчик и ведем адресацию со смещением т.е. [esi+ebx] например. Вообще изучение ассемблера надо не с вызова функций ОС начинать, а с изучения системы команд и адресации

Comment: Почти первое что выдает гугл на "assembler HeapAlloc" http://kipirvine.com/asm/articles/heap_allocation.pdf  неплохие примеры там, с заполнением области памяти значением, например

Comment: @Mike ну я вобщем сделал "mov ebx, [hMylp1]" и всё вроде бы отлично работает, но моя программа стала считаться как вирус по мнению лицензионного Kaspersky, как вы думаете что можно сделать чтоб он не ругался ? :)

Comment: Не представляю, он же по сигнатурам обычно ищет, что ему могло не понравится в таком коде ума не приложу. это же распространенные методы работы, я бы сказал единственные. Раз касперский лицензионный - наверное можно спросить в службе поддержки :)

Comment: Насчёт обратиться в службу поддержки это хорошая идея )